# Upper bound for x

Tags: equation-solving

I want to ask a question about `Reduce`. I have a function, say `f[x]`. When I use the command  `Reduce[f[x] > 0, {x}]`, it gives me an interval for `x`. But, I don't want to have an interval. I want to have an upper bound for `x`.

For example: After the command `Reduce[f[x] > 0, {x}]`, the output is `a_1 < x < a_2`. But I want to have only `a_2`. How can I get it?

Comment: Make sure you use the correct "brackets", i.e. `f(x)` vs. `f[x]`

Comment: @ Pinguin Dirk, you are right. i refit it.

Comment: A direct answer would depend on the details of your `f`; for the example you made try `Part[a1 < x < a2, -1]`.

Comment: E.g. `Reduce[27 > x^3 > 8, x] // Last` yields `3`.

Comment: Sometimes there just isn't an upperbound for x. Take for instance x^2-1>0.

Comment: `Maximize[{f[x],f[x]>0}, x]` is perhaps what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that the question is simply how to take an inequality such as

```
interv = a1 < x < a2
```

and extract the *upper* limit from it. This could work:

```
Simplify[Max[List @@ interv], interv]

(* ==> a2 *)
```